# Change Button's image appearance when enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, mvvm

Currently I have buttons in WPF but I want them to appear lighter when they are disabled and full colored when they are enabled. Is there an option to make the image lighter automatically, or I need to edit them in inkscape and import as a completely different image and change the image `Source` in the ViewModel.

The code currently being used by one of the buttons:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding SettingsButtonIsEnabled}" Command="{Binding OnSaveProject}" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="{DynamicResource SaveProject}">
    <Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="/Axon.Oscillographic.Viewer;component/Icons/save.png"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: you may use converter that return the color on a specific case(for example: `IsEnabled`) and set `BackgroundColor` to that color

Comment: But i need to make the img lighter or in black and white. Not just the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to reduce the image `Opacity`, when button is disabled. This could be done via Style with a DataTrigger:

```
<Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="/Axon.Oscillographic.Viewer;component/Icons/save.png">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" 
                              Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.75"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```